# Java fixed thread pool race condition?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, race-condition, synchronized

Consider the following code:

```
private static final Object LOCK = new Object();
private static final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10); // Also used for a few other tasks.

public static void save(Object o) {
    String s = serialize(o);
    executorService.submit(() -> {
        // Do we have a race condition here?
        synchronized (LOCK) {
            saveToFile(s, new File("test.txt")); // overwrites the file
        }
    });
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    save(args[0]);
    save(args[1]);
}
```

`save(Object o)` is only invoked on the main thread. I know that the thread pool processes the submitted tasks from the internal queue in order but could it happen in theory, that there is a race condition before `synchronized (LOCK)` is reached and the file output is `args[0]`?

If yes, how can this be avoided? I know that a single thread executor would definitely solve this problem but I want to use this thread pool if possible.

**Edit:** I think one possible way is to use a `Queue`:

```
private static final Queue<String> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

public static void save(Object o) {
    queue.add(serialize(o));
    executorService.submit(() -> {
        synchronized (LOCK) {
            saveToFile(queue.remove(), new File("test.txt"));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: " that there is a race condition before `synchronized (LOCK)` is reached" --> Yes.
" the file output is `args[0]`" --> not always, this depends on the outcome of the race. But, what are you trying to avoid?

Comment: @boobalan the race condition. The output should be `args[1]` guaranteed.

Comment: if `args[1]` is the output you want anyway, why do you call `args[0]`? Or you need `args[1]` to be output, just because it is the last one to get submitted?

Comment: I think I found a way to do this, however I am wondering if there is a better solution.

Comment: @boobalan This is just a demo code to "provoke" the race condition. Yes because it's the last one.

Comment: You can create a Lock, a Condition and a common counter and each time, the program waits for the last one to finish.

Comment: I'd totally get rid of the lock.. its not necesarry..

As the answer below shows you want the save to be quick and clean by making save() add to a queue and then returning. 

Let other threads then pick it up and save to the file.
The whole point of util.concurrent is to avoid synchronized

Comment: @AminM the fact that the code in assylias answer is safe without a lock has nothing to do with the `Queue` from `java.util.concurrent` but rather that only one thread of the pool is used. Effectively this is the same as a single thread executor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a producer / consumer pattern like yours, you typically transfer the tasks between the (multiple) producers and the (single) consumer via [a blocking queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html). The fact that there is a single consumer ensures the order of the execution.

So in pseudo code it would be something like this:

```
val queue = ArrayBlockingQueue() //could be another BlockingQueue
val executor = ...

main {
  executor.submit(consumer)
  queue.put(args[0])
  queue.put(args[1])
}

consumer() {
  try {
    while (true) {
      val file = queue.take() //blocks until a file is added to the queue
      save(file)
    }
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    Thread.currentThread(interrupt()) //restore the interrupt flag
    //do nothing, just exit
  }
}
```

If you add more consumers, you can't guarantee that the files will be processed in order. But you can add as many producers as you want (i.e. adding to the queue from different threads).

Comment: I'd suggest changing the name of your method to consumer() since the method is consuming not producing.

Comment: Interesting, but doing it this way would "occupy" one thread of the pool the entire time. Not quite what I'm looking for. But I like the idea. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "occupy one thread"? The thread will either be doing some work, saving the file, or it will be in waiting state (not using any CPU resources).

Comment: I know it's not using CPU while waiting. But the pool has a fixed amount of threads. And one of those isn't usable anymore for other tasks then.

Comment: @stonar96 I don't see how that's a problem. If you need one more thread for the other tasks, just add one thread to your pool. On a 64bit JVM, a thread will typically be allocated a stack size of 1MB so unless you are very constrained memory wise, it should not make much difference.

Comment: Why not make the consumer take one element, instead of looping, and submit the consumer as many times as elements have been put into the queue? That avoids blocking a thread and still guarantees to write in the queue order.

Comment: Yes I totally agree, you can add an extra thread to the pool for this, but then I could also just use a new single thread executor just for this purpose. But the main problem is that I can't change the thread pool, it is created somewhere else and provided. All I can do is using it. Nevertheless I'll accept the answer because it is a valid option to do it this way.
@Holger So you mean basically what I have already done in my question?

Comment: @stonar96 yes, that way.